Call Databricks notebook without specifying parameters from an external notebook
I have main notebook main_notebook. I am going to call an external notebook notebook1 which has 2 parameters param1 and param2, but I do not want to specify parameters name, I know parameters orders. I want something like this:
dbutils.notebook.run("/path/to/notebook1", 60, {"param1_value", "param2_value"}) 

But this does not work and I could not find any solution.
